# Selenium Webdriver: not printing text in 'td' tab

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have this HTML within a webpage:

```html
<li style="list-style-type: none">
        <h2 class="section-head"><a href=""><span class="user_data_property_name">Experimental Vapor Pressure:</span></a></h2>
        <table style="display:none">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td valign="top">75 mmHg <strong>NIOSH</strong>  <a target="_new" href="http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/npg/npgd0049.html" title="NIOSH - CY1400000" onclick="partnerLink(137,'http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/npg/npgd0049.html','link');">CY1400000</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
      </li>
```

I am trying to print the text within the 'tr' tab, specifically "75 mmHg" and "NIOSH".
I am able to select this 'li' tab in a variable called `vp_li`, and when I call `print(vp_li.text)`, it prints 'Experimental Vapor Pressure:'.

```
vp_li = extable.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[3]
vp = vp_li.find_element_by_xpath("table/tbody/tr/td")
print(vp.text)
```

When I run this, however, it only prints a blank line. How can I get the data I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it prints 'Experimental Vapor Pressure:'

This is because `.text` by default would get you the *visible text* only.

You can workaround it by getting the `textContent` attribute:

```
vp_li = extable.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[3] 
print(vp_li.get_attribute("textContent"))
```